# Problem with sending messages from a silverlight client using websockes prototype

Tags: silverlight, websocket

I need to use websockets for implementing a bi-directional communication between my silverlight client and the server. I could connect/disconnect to/from the server and both *OnOpen* & *OnClose* events in both of client and server fired well, but i have a problem with sending messages to the server :
when I send a message to the server, I don't get any error at the client side where as the *OnMessage* operation of my service at the server never called(the message sent from client without any problem but server never receive that!).
You can get my sample code [here](http://cid-8b3b5259a5661cf0.office.live.com/self.aspx/.Documents/Codes/WebsocketSample.rar).
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "One additional restriction on using
>   the sockets classes is that the
>   destination port range that a network
>   application is allowed to connect to
>   must be within the range of 4502-4534.
>   These are the only destination ports
>   allowed by a connection from a
>   Silverlight application using
>   sockets."
>
> Source:
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032%28v=VS.95%29.aspx
>
> Having a policy file will only make it
>   work with the mentioned port range.
>   Without a policy file it will not work
>   at all. **These two (and many more)
>   restrictions do not apply to trusted
>   applications.**

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/silverlightdeveloper/thread/b4f7120d-71d9-4132-9c31-b456803cd32f

---

**Update**

try to change your policy file to this:

```
<access-policy>
<cross-domain-access>
<policy>
  <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
    <domain uri="*" />
  </allow-from>
  <grant-to>
    <socket-resource port="4502-4534" protocol="tcp" />
  </grant-to>
</policy>
</cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

Comment: @Ai_boy: first thanks for the reply. then: I have the clientaccesspolicy.xml file everywhere(you can see that in the projects), next to the server.exe , web project root, wwwroot, and my sl client, but I have that problem, please see the project if you don't see that previous.

Comment: first of all.. try to run your silverlight project "out of browser".. go to "Project -> Properies -> Silverlight -> Enable running out of browser" set it to True.. then go to "Out-Of-Browser Setting -> Requre evaluated trust.." set it to True.. then try to run your appp..

Comment: @Ai_boy: thanks this works well, but i need to run my sl app inside of browser,do you have any idea about this? (why this works well in out of browser mode?)

Comment: Any idea about running this sample inside of browser?

Answer (score 1):

Policy file exist only on server side.

Please take a look on :
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

You can deliver policy file on HTTP or by a policy server (on port 943).

*To use HTTP to retrieve the socket policy file, an application should set the SocketAsyncEventArgs::SocketClientAccessPolicyProtocol property to Http on the System.Net.Sockets::SocketAsyncEventArgs instance passed to the Socket::ConnectAsync method.*

Good luck

Comment: thanks for the reply, i read that msdn article, i also have the policy file in both of the server & client, could you correct my sample or get a sample that works with the websockets prototype well?